# 2D rendering libraries (and video) for Linux

Tags: linux, animation, video, svg, 2d

I want to write a system that takes a simple DSL, converts that into a 2D animation, and renders it as video.  When I say "animation," I mean something along the lines of a title sequence generator or a fancy version of PowerPoint (as opposed to, say, an animated cartoon).  I'm a Linux developer, and so ideally it would use either the C stack or Java.

I've been pondering various options, but I feel like I might be missing something.  For example, there's embedded SVG animation (using Batik or librsvg).  That would be easy to target, but the SVG animation implementations seem incomplete and slightly bug-prone, and it's not clear how one would transcode it into video.

On the other end, there are things like SDL (combined with ffmpeg?) -- which obviously provides a lot of functionality, but might be overkill.  I see systems like synfig and Blender, but it doesn't seem as if those are really intended for people who want to write to an API.  The same might be true of Processing, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Since the animation isn't as complex as the sort of thing you'd see in a game, it might be possible to generate stills and stitch them together (though that seems pretty inefficient to me).  But even there, I'm not sure what libraries are ideal.

I hope I'm describing the project correctly.  I suppose I'm imagining a version of Adobe Flex with a more constrained set of possible outputs (and, again, targeting video).

Comment: You could use Qt; it has nice QGraphicsScene & animation abilities.

Answer (score 0):

or then you could use flash and it's likes. or the flash implementations on linux. or javafx and whatnot.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to subvert Flash . . . ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JavaFX and see if it fits for you.

JavaFX has transitions, effects, blends, animation, video playback, strokes, fills, gradients, text and image manipulation, html display and editing, parallel and perspective cameras, hardware acceleration, etc.

JavaFX 2.2 lacks a video capture capability, so you would need to supplement it with something like ffmpeg or some other library.

Groovy or Scala could be used to create and run the DSL, and the DSL could invoke GroovyFX or ScalaFX JavaFX wrapper libs.  Or you could just parse and run your DSL using a plain java app to avoid those languages if you wished.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/

http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/canned-animations/